# Dynamically created "read more" link expands all the content instead of just one

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I was trying to code was the following:

1. Find every div of given class
2. If one of them happens to be higher than my maximum, make it 75px high and hide overflow, and add a "read more link" after this specific oversized element.
3. Make the link work...

I succeeded up to no. 2. However, the link on click expands all the content in all divs starting from the one it should expand downwards.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
        $(function() {
            $('.text').each(function() {
                var content = $(this).find('.text_content');
                if(content.outerHeight() >75) {
                    content.css('height','75px').css('overflow','hidden');
                    content.after('<div class="text_readmore">read more</div>');
                    $('.text_readmore').each(function() {
                        $(this).click(function() {
                            content.css('height','').css('overflow','');
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `content` variable inside your `.click` handler, which isn't point to what you want. You can also refactor your code so that `.click` handler is defined once for all such `text_readmore` links, for efficiency.

Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.text').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).find('.text_content');
        if(content.outerHeight() >75) {
            content.css('height','75px').css('overflow','hidden');
            content.after('<div class="text_readmore">read more</div>');
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.text_readmore', function() { // event delegation
    $(this).closest('.text_content').css('height','').css('overflow','');
});
```

If you're using a version of jQuery before 1.7 (which is when [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was added), use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead:

```
$(document).delegate('.text_readmore', 'click', function() { // event delegation
    $(this).closest('.text_content').css('height','').css('overflow','');
});
```

Comment: Hmmmmm... It doesn't seem to work to me. May it be because of using jQuery 1.6.4?

Looks like it doesn't execute anything in:
    $(document).on('click', '.text_readmore', function() { ... });

Comment: That does make a difference, yes. Updated answer.